# Java - Using Proxy Classes

Tags: java, proxy-classes

So I have a couple of classes `ClassA` through `ClassC` (not implemented by myself, so I can't modify their source). Each class implements some common functions, and some unique ones. These classes are used to provide different types of authentication behavior to a datasource. So for instance, here is an example of what each class implements:

```
// Uses pre-configured privileged user credentials to get data
ClassA.getUsers(...)

// Saves session to allow user to log-in once and perform any operation after that without repeated authentication
ClassB.login(Username, Password)
ClassB.logout()
ClassB.getUsers(..., Username, Password)

// Uses given token to authenticate user and get data
ClassC.getUsers(..., Token)
```

I am trying to develop a `ProxyClass` for these classes such that I can make calls like so:

```
ProxyClass
  .getUsers(...);                     => calls ClassA.getUsers(...)

ProxyClass
  .authenticate(Token)
  .getUsers(...);                     => calls ClassC.getUsers(..., Token)

T obj = ProxyClass
  .authenticate(Username, Password);  => calls ClassD.login(Username, Password)

obj.getUsers(...)                     => calls ClassD.getUsers(...)
obj.logout()                          => calls ClassD.logout();
```

Is this even possible? If it possible, can someone guide me as to how the `ProxyClass` will look like?

Is it possible to ensure that, for instance, if `ClassC` did not have `getUsers()`, then `ProxyClass.authentication(Token).` would not show `getUsers` at all?

Is it possible to do something like if a method in the proxied classes is declared as `void`, we return an instance of the proxied class again, so the caller of proxy can chain calls together?

A full solution, if possible, would definitely be nice. But I'll settle for a partial one as well. If I have a good starting point, I can probably work out the remainder. But right now I don't know how to even begin implementing it in the first place. :(

Thanks, AweSIM

---

*EDIT* I think I should've mentioned that by `ProxyClass`, I meant `DynamicProxy` classes. Which involves reflection in method invoking. If that's not possible, or not insanely complicated, I guess I'll have to settle with static proxy classes.

Comment: Why do ClassB need credentials two times?

Comment: You dont need a dynamic Proxy to invoke methods via reflection. But in this particular case I don't see any reasons to even use reflection, It can be solved with pure oop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

```
package utils;

public class ProxyClasses {

    public static class ClassA {
        public void function1(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) {}
    }
    public static class ClassB {
        public void function1(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, String username, String password) {}
    }
    public static class ClassC {
        public void function1(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, String token) {}
    }

    public static interface ClassCommon {
        ProxyClasses function1(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3); // or whatever
    }
    public static class ProxyClass implements ClassCommon {
        @Override
        public void function1(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) {
            new ClassA().function1(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        }

        public ClassCommon authenticate() {
            return new ClassCommon() {
                @Override
                public void function1(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) {
                    new ClassA().function1(arg1, arg2, arg3);
                    return this;
                }
            };
        }
        public ClassCommon authenticate(final String username, final String password) {
            ClassB classB = new ClassB();
            classB.login(username, password);
            return new ClassCommon() {
                @Override
                public void function1(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) {
                    new ClassB().function1(arg1, arg2, arg3, username, password);
                    return this;
                }
            };
        }
        public ClassCommon authenticate(final String token) {
            return new ClassCommon() {
                @Override
                public void function1(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) {
                    new ClassC().function1(arg1, arg2, arg3, token);
                    return this;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```